# Offering EJB to clients using HTTP

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm developing a server to offer persistence to clients connecting through http. The clients will be based on different technologies: web, iphone and android; that is why I thought of using http in the first place (may be there is a better approach).

In the server I'm using a javaee 6 implementation with EJBs and JPA to achieve my persistence goal and servlets to offer access to the EJBs interfaces to the clients.
The servlets are just dummy proxies, so I'm sure there has to be a framework or a better way of offering my EJB as a service to my clients.

I'm trying to find a way of avoiding all the dummy proxy servlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement [RESTful Web Services with JAX-RS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html)

Comment: I reached the same conclusion and ended up using the Jersey API.